# izecss dynamic text fit inside elastic div

Tags: jquery, css, fluid-layout

how can I make my dynamic text to fit inside a elastic/fluid div?

so I have a fluid div and some text. I want to make that text size as big as it fits to the div and adapt when the div is changing size.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your problem exactly, but according to what i could get is that you can use **min-height** and **min-width** property of css.

Comment: Do you want your font size to increase with div size. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
align="justify"
```

for inline and

```
text-align: justify
```

for css.